# Loading non-specific clicked image in new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

From my searching on here and via google, I could not find a complete solution to what I'm searching.

**Overview:**

I have one page that has a div with some images. That loads fine and I have it set to open a new page/tab when clicking/tapping them.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="scrollmenu">
    <a href="./screenshots.html" target="_blank">
        <img src="./screenshots/1.png" width="60%" target="_new"/>&nbsp;
    </a>
    <a href="./screenshots.html" target="_blank">
        <img src="./screenshots/2.png" width="60%" target="_new"/>&nbsp;
    </a>
    <a href="./screenshots.html" target="_blank">
        <img src="./screenshots/3.png" width="60%" target="_new"/>&nbsp;
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem:**

While that even opens the screenshots.html, the image won't load.

Now I know I need to do some stuff in the screenshots.html file to receive the clicked image, I just don't know what.

This is what I have set up so far in that file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/style.css"/>
<title>Screenshots</title>
</head>

<body class="no-pinstripe">
<panel>

  <!--This is where is needs to be loaded up -->
  <img src="./screenshots/*.png" width="60%">

</panel>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to do to receive and load the clicked image in there?

Suggested javascript I have come across. Just don't know how to link things up.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    if (location.search)
    {
        var image_filename = location.search.substring(1)
        document.write('<IMG SRC="' + image_filename + '">')
        //document.write('<IMG "STYLE="width:60%" SRC="' + image_filename + '">')
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have your written any js?

Comment: I personally have not, I have added a suggested piece that I have come across before while tinkering.

Comment: Better to tinker, than not (thumbs up). I'll try to write an answer, although someone may beat me to it.

Comment: Someone beat me to it :)

Comment: I appreciate the help. As I just commented to the answer, it doesn't open a new page and also the image opened is broken.

Comment: I think you may need to "tinker" as @Prasad answer works well.

Comment: For the most part it does work well. Still opening only a blank page instead of the image now. Half way there :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your first page as like this.Pass the img src via hash tag with url

***Update*** .You folder path like this

```
main_folder 
         => firsthtmlpage//image call => "./screenshots/images.png"
screenshots
         => images.png
screenshot.html(secondhtmlpage)) //the image "screenshots/images.png"
```

I have create one project for you code [`check this`](https://thimbleprojects.org/prasanth1036/271904/) .it open new window.and show the which image are you clicked.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollmenu">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <img src="./screenshots/1.png" width="60%" target="_new" />&nbsp;
    </a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <img src="./screenshots/2.png" width="60%" target="_new" />&nbsp;
    </a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <img src="./screenshots/3.png" width="60%" target="_new" />&nbsp;
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('.scrollmenu a').click(function() {
    window.open("screenshots.html#" + encodeURIComponent($(this).children('img').attr('src')))
  })
</script>
```

**And**

Change the screenshots.html page like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/style.css"/>
    <title>Screenshots</title>
    </head>
    <body class="no-pinstripe">
    <panel>

      <!--This is where is needs to be loaded up -->
      <img src="" width="60%">
   <script>
        window.onload=function(){
 $('img').attr('src',decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash).replace(/#|\.\//g,"").trim())
        }

      </script>
    </panel>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: While this may be on the right path for me, it doesn't open a new page. As it stands right now, it opens a broken image. I don't know if the *.png is the right formatting I need? I only placed that as a non specific image.

Comment: @ChrisOSX see my updated answer.Check that link .and change your code as like that

Comment: Ok, now we're on the right path. Opening in a new page works fine, but upon opening that page, nothing gets loaded up. I thought it might have been the image link, so I got the full address of the image. Nothing. I've looked at the answer you provided, even inspected element on both pages. They are identical. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChrisOSX keep the both html page in same folder .Its different folder change the path of the image.follow my updated answer

Comment: Ok so I double and triple checked the folders. My index.html (main page) and screenshots.html (image loader) are in the same location. Upon looking at the url I'm not sure if it's decoding properly. it shows up as "/screenshots.html#.%2Fscreenshots%2F1.png" Shouldn't it just be screenshots.html and then the script embeds the decoded image link in the <img src="" width="60%"> ?

Comment: *`decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash).replace(/#|\.\//g,"").trim()`* its decode the `"/screenshots.html#.%2Fscreenshots%2F1.png"` with `./screenshots/2(any).png` .Then placed with the Img tag src .check `console.log(decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash).replace(/#|\.\//g,"").trim())` it shows like the `./screenshots/2(any).png` .if show with same check the image path from this page

Comment: Still only opening the screenshots.html with no attached image.